# How do I install eclipse 3.5.1-0 ubuntu7?

Tags: linux, eclipse

I am very new to linux and I do some programming for school in Eclipse. However I stumbled upon bug in eclipse and the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965285/bug-in-eclipse-not-showing-anything-in-install-software-screen) was to install eclipse 3.5.1-0 ubuntu7 using Synaptic.

I opened synaptic but it said that the latest version was just eclipse 3.5.1-0 ubuntu3 so installed it anyway however the bug is still there and I'd like to install eclipse 3.5.1-0 ubuntu7 but I don't know how since Synaptic insists that the latest version is ubuntu3.

I am using Linux mint btw. A bug report of the bug I am experiencing can be found [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/443004)

Answer (score 1):

1) Download eclipse from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

2) Extract with

```
tar xzf eclipse-jee-galileo-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz
```

Comment: (or eclipse-jee-galileo-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz if you install the 64bit version)

Comment: Hi I first installed this way and then I found something was wrong so the suggestion was to install from synaptic 3.5.1-0 ubuntu7 but apparently my synaptic is saying that the latest eclipse is 3.5.1-0 ubuntu3

Comment: What command are you giving to aptitude? It should always give you the latest version unless you specifically specify otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [downloading](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/galileo/SR1/eclipse-java-galileo-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz) (Link for Eclipse Java IDE) and installing the latest eclipse from their [site](http://www.eclipse.org)?

Comment: Hi, yes this is the version that actually has the bug and the suggestion was to install from synaptic.

Comment: Latest version is the one linked here. Synaptic only has 3.5.1-0 ubuntu3. If you want 3.5.1-0 ubuntu7 I think you're going to need to install from the gzip.

Comment: My original installation the buggy one was from the gzip and that's when I was recommended to install ubuntu7 from Synaptic but apparently it wasn't in the repositories. So guess I am back to square one. hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

Aptitude should always get you the latest version of eclipse *in the ubuntu repository*.
(Currently 3.5.1+repack~1-0ubuntu3)

If the "download the gzip and install" isn't working for you I suppose it's worth trying installing the repository version and upgrading from there. 
You have some issue with your current eclipse install, so let's back up settings and reinstall

```
cd ~
mv .eclipse .eclipse.old
sudo aptitude remove eclipse
```

You may also want to rename / move your workspace directory. Default is ~/workspace.

```
cd ~
mv workspace workspace.old
```

Now install eclipse

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install eclipse
```

You will still have the version in the repository.

Run eclipse.

```
Window->Preferences
Install/Update->Available Software
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/
Help->Check for updates
```

Open the same window again. Select all the sources it found, enable them.

Check for updates again.

```
Help->Install new software
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/
```

Install eclipse packages you desire.

Comment: Disclaimer; installing from synaptic is a really bad idea imho. The version there is ancient. This method of updating successfully updated Ganymede to Galileo for me, but "apt-cache policy eclipse" still reports 3.5.1-ubuntu3. I don't really know how updating apps outside synaptic affects managed synaptic packages to be honest.

Comment: Actually I realized that installing eclipse using aptitude/synaptic et. al gives me the Classic Eclipse. I need the eclipse for Java EE. and keying in the command sudo apt-cache search eclipse doesn't yield a Java EE result. hahaha. Now I have two problems how to install eclipse Java EE and how to update to the latest fixed version.

Comment: Sorry, I'm losing track. What's the problem with the gzip download from eclipse.org? I thought you wanted the version from synaptic.

Comment: The version from eclipse.org has a bug in it. See edited post.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of eclipse on ubuntu repositories is 3.5.1+repack~1-0ubuntu3.

To install a later version you need to download from eclipse website. (As per [this](https://superuser.com/questions/89755/how-do-i-install-eclipse-3-5-1-0-ubuntu7/89778#89778) answer).